# Phoenix Ecto ** (Mariaex.Error) (1054): Unknown column 'inserted_at' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, elixir, phoenix-framework

When inserting a model into MySQL database using Elixir + Phoenix I get:

```
** (Mariaex.Error) (1054): Unknown column 'inserted_at' in 'field list'
     stacktrace:
       (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/mysql.ex:181: Ecto.Adapters.MySQL.insert/5
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:381: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:185: anonymous fn/11 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_insert/4
       (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:595: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.wrap_in_transaction/6
       (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:472: anonymous fn/3 in Ecto.Adapters.SQL.do_transaction/3
       (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:973: DBConnection.transaction_run/4
       (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:897: DBConnection.run_begin/3
       (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:671: DBConnection.transaction/3
```

This is not happening with other models, which work ok. 
Model schema is:

```
  schema "accounts" do
    field :key, :string, null: false
    field :cypher_key, :string, null: false
    field :another_key, :string, null: false
    field :another_cypher_key, :string, null: false
    belongs_to :user, MyApp.User
    timestamps()
  end
```

and when inserting I'm doing:

```
Repo.insert! %Account{key: "test",
                      cypher_key: "test",
                      another_key: "test",
                      another_cypher_key: "pk_test"
             }
```

When manually inserting via MySQL cmd it works ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your table contain `timestamps` fields? Did you generate proper migration for that?

Use `mix ecto.gen.migration` and then open file, which will be created in `/priv/repo/migrations`.

Alter the `change` function into something similar this:

```
def change do
  create table(:accounts) do
    add :key, :string
    # etc.

    timestamps
  end

  create unique_index(:accounts, [:key])
end
```

Then apply this migration with `mix ecto.migrate`.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite likely that you didn't add `timestamps` in your migration file. For both the `Ecto.Schema` and the migration file, the `timestamps` function references two fields: `updated_at` and `inserted_at`. If you happen to come from Ruby on Rails, you may notice the naming difference from `created_at`. See [the docs here](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Migration.html#timestamps/1) for more detail.